# RmarkdownでWordファイルの生成

Tags: r, markdown

Rmarkdownを用いて.RmdファイルからWordファイルの生成を行っていますが2つ気になるところがあるので質問させていただきます。

1,TeXを用いてpdfファイルを作る場合は自動でページ数が振られるので問題ないのですが、Wordファイルの場合は自動でページ数を入れる方法はあるのでしょうか？

2,普通にWordを用いて文書作成するときと比べRmdファイルから生成した場合行間がスカスカになるのですがどのように対処すればよいでしょうか？（特に見出しの##などを用いたあたりがスカスカになります）

どちらも生成されたdocxファイルを弄っても解決できますがRmdファイルから解決する方法があれば知りたいです。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1と2の両方について，docx形式の場合，RMarkdown上での設定はありません。しかし，予めWordでページ設定をした.docxファイルを準備し，Rmdファイルの冒頭で以下のように指定するとできるはずです:

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: mystyles.docx
---
```

このように，すでに自分用にカスタマイズした書式参照用のdocxを準備して読みこませれば解決します。ただ一から設定を構築するには手間がかかりますので，一旦適当なRmdファイルをdocxで出力し，そのファイルに対して書式設定を施すと楽になると思います。
これについては，英語ですが，この資料が参考になるかと思います。

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html